# Listings caption alignment in list environments

Tags: listings, captions, positioning, lists

I'm having trouble with the alignment of captions of `lstlisting` inside environments like `description` or `enumerate`. I'm using the `listings` and `caption` packages.

As soon as I try setting the caption position to bottom, the caption is no longer aligned with the listing. In the example below, the alignment is correct for listings 1 and 2, but wrong for 3. The issue persists also with default centered captions. Moreover, `listings` does not seem to respect some of the global options set with `captionsetup`, like the position.

How can I achieve captions under listings that have proper alignment?

[image: Example]

The MWE for reproducing this 'issue' is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{fmt}{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1#2#3}}
\captionsetup{textfont=it,justification=raggedright,format=fmt,position=bottom}
\lstset{frame=single}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Hello World!}]
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{description}
\item[A]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Hello World!}]
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Hello World!},captionpos=b]
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\item[B]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the `caption` package to me. I created an issue and will take a closer look ASAP. https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/26

Comment: Fixed with caption.sty v3.4d which will be uploaded to CTAN on Feb 2020.

Comment: ...just uploaded it to CTAN right now. (Release 2020-01-03)